# How to create neural network with 35 inputs and 1 output?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm new to machine learning. I'm using Keras to build the following neural network for binary classification: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKver.png)

So I need 35x10 input and 1 binary output. And also I want to train a model on 1 data point at a time. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

model_online_1 = Sequential()
model_online_1.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=tuple([grouped_X_train.shape[1]])))
model_online_1.add(Dense(35, batch_size=35, input_dim=10))
model_online_1.add(Activation('relu'))
model_online_1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_online_1.add(Dense(35))
model_online_1.add(Activation('relu'))
model_online_1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_online_1.add(Dense(1))
model_online_1.add(Activation('softmax'))
model_online_1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

batch_size = 1
nb_classes = 2
nb_epoch = 1

for i in range(no_of_samples):
    # train on ith data point
    model_online_1.fit(grouped_X_train[i].T, [grouped_Y1_train[i]],
                       batch_size, nb_epoch,
                        verbose=0)
```

And while fitting I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/natalia/PycharmProjects/raw_recognition/classification.py", line 139, in <module>
    verbose=0)
  File "/home/natalia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/natalia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 637, in _standardize_user_data
    training_utils.check_array_length_consistency(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "/home/natalia/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 244, in check_array_length_consistency
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 10 input samples and 1 target samples.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is wrong with the model? The last dense layer should return 1 output or  I misunderstand this?

Update: Grouped_X_train.shape: (26, 35, 10) Grouped_Y1_train.shape: (26,)

Comment: print shape of grouped_X_train and Y_train.

Comment: Grouped_X_train.shape: (26, 35, 10)
Grouped_Y1_train.shape: (26,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your input shape is wrong. It should be (35, 10)

`model_online_1.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(35,10)))`

2. It's an unusual choice to use BatchNorm at first layer.
3. You again specify `input_dim` and `batch_size` in your second dense layer, which is another issue. How do you make up these non-existent parameters?

`model_online_1.add(Dense(35))`

4. Your last layer should be `sigmoid` not `softmax`.

`model_online_1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))`

5. Your loss should be `binary_crossentropy`

`model_online_1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')`

- N.B: I'm assuming it's a binary classification problem.

Comment: If you use Dense as first layer then, `model_online_1.add(Dense(35, input_shape=(35,10)))`

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I'll do like this, error is: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (35, 10)
model_online_1 = Sequential()
model_online_1.add(Dense(35, input_shape=(35,10)))
model_online_1.add(Activation('relu'))
model_online_1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_online_1.add(Dense(35))
model_online_1.add(Activation('relu'))
model_online_1.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_online_1.add(Dense(1))
model_online_1.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model_online_1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')